# Checkbox in my dialogfragment, which when checked, does not display the dialog again

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

MyDialogFragment.java

```
public class MyDialogFragmentComunicados extends DialogFragment {

    public static MyDialogFragmentComunicados newInstance(int title) {
        MyDialogFragmentComunicados frag = new MyDialogFragmentComunicados();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("title", title);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int title = getArguments().getInt("Dica");

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        return builder
                .setTitle("title")
                .setMessage("message")
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        dismiss();

                    }
                })
                .create();
    }
}
```

code that calls the class in my fragment

```
DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance(R.string.my_string);
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

I need a checkbox in my dialogfragment that when checked, do not display this dialog again.

Comment: where did you implement checkbox in the dialog box @Caio V.?

Comment: i dont, i need and i dont know how do that